# Fetching multiple nested collections eagerly in separate SELECTs using NHibernate

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, prefetch

I have the following database structure, which I need to traverse entirely for a report.

```
Product -> ProductVariation -> ProductMedaItem
Product -> CategoryLinks -> Category
```

I have a query on the `Products` table, and want to prefetch the above data, as I will be accessing them all together. I want to avoid using JOINs, as the combinations would explode and result in loads of data.

The ideal solution in my eyes would be the following:

- A query is issued to load all matching products
- Then, the result set is parsed, and all product variations are loaded together, based on a query similar to '`Select * from ProductVariations where ProductId in ([all_product_id_set])`;
- Again, this result set is parsed and all `ProductMediaItem` are fetched using a query similar to `Select * from ProductMediaItem where ProductVariationId in ([all_product_variation_id_set]);`
- So on and so forth

This would result in one `SELECT` for each different association. Thus, to load all product variations, their media items, and each products category links, and their respective categories would result in 5 `SELECT`s.

I have tried using `criteria.SetFetchMode("ProductVariations", FetchMode.Select")`, but this does nothing. My current workaround is to use batching, but this still results in around 50 - 60 queries to get all the data, which although not so slow, I think it could be made much faster.

I am using the latest version of NHibernate - 3.3.

***Update 1***

I would like to traverse the collection using normal OOP, example:

```
foreach (var p in Products)
{
    foreach (var variation in p.ProductVariations)
    {
        foreach (var mediaItem in variation.MediaItems)
        {
              ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MultiQueries and MultiCriteria will work, or even easier would be futures, eg:

```
var productVariations = session.CreateQuery(
        "Select * from ProductVariations where ProductId in ([all_product_id_set])")
        .Future<ProductVariations>();

var mediaItems = session.CreateQuery(
        "select pv.MediaItems from ProductVariations pv where pv.ProductId in ([all_product_id_set])")
        .Future<ProductMediaItem>();
```

etc...
When you enumerate any of them it will execute all the queries in 1 go, the only "trick" is to navigate down the relationship from Product to the various items you want to select

Comment: That would work, but I would like that NHibernate prefetches the collections automatically for me, using the normal code structure.  Thus, I would load the list of products, and if I access say `Products[0].ProductVariations[0].ProductMediaItems[0]`, there is no need to go and fetch them, but they are already there.